# jquery datepicker position above text field

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I would like to keep the datepicker (jquery and jquery UI theme) calendar above the textfield, because at the moment if the datepicker calendar is below the textfield, then on mobile devices the virtual keyboard covers all of the calendar.

Comment: u can try `orientation: "bottom auto"` param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can change css file

something like this

```
.ui-datepicker {
    position: relative !important;
    top: -290px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```